# Ansible yaml rearrangement causes error

Tags: yaml, ansible

The `my_tags` fact assignment is working in the second assignment. The first assignment listed causes a failure, but it's just a simple rearrangement. And yes, I commented/uncommented correctly when I ran it.

Here's the code:

```
- name: Set optional tag
  when: machine_type.find('substr') != -1
  set_fact:
    # vvv some quoting error? vvv
    my_tags: {{ my_tags | default('') }}, sbc_type:{{ direction }},
    # vvv works just fine vvv
    #my_tags: sbc_type:{{ direction }}, {{ my_tags | default('') }}
```

And here is the error:

```
    my_tags: {{ my_tags | default('') }}, sbc_type:{{ direction }},
                                        ^
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.
```

When I copy-pasted from my terminal to here, the carat (^) was pointing to the 'direction' variable if that's any clue, but I didn't see any tabs being used.

Why does the rearrangement cause this error?

Comment: try to `" "` quote either 1st or 2nd or both set of `{{ }}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented in [Hey Wait, A YAML gotcha](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#hey-wait-a-yaml-gotcha):

> YAML syntax requires that if you start a value with {{ foo }} you
>   quote the whole line, since it wants to be sure you aren’t trying to
>   start a YAML dictionary.

So you should write this:

```
my_tags: "{{ my_tags | default('') }}, sbc_type:{{ direction }},"
```